# Turn a video into a sequence of images using GStreamer (not ffmpeg)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I have an ogg vorbis video. It plays fine in totem and mplayer. I want to covert it to a sequnces of images, one image per frame. I can do this on ffmpeg with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.ogv -f image 2 video-frames-%08png
```

However that doesn't work for this video. Each frame is all grey as if there has been loads of decoding problems. Since it works in totem, I suspect that gstreamer is better able to decode the video than ffmpeg. Is there a gstreamer command that will take in a ogg vorbis video and then create a pile of images, one for each frame?

I'm using stock Ubuntu Lucid desktop.

Comment: Actually, the correct command line for ffmpeg seems to be `ffmpeg -i video.ogv -an -f image2 "video-frames-%08d.png"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try multifilesink:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=video.ogv ! decodebin ! pngenc ! multifilesink location=img%d.png
```

Comment: Yep that works. However I had to change it to jpgenc, not pngenc. If it was pngnec, it would just hang and the pipeline was stuck on "PREROLLING".